# Calculate Gradient (Partial Derivatives) of Bezier Curve

Tags: partial-derivative, bezier-curve

From this page I know that a Bezier curve of degree $N$ has a derivative which is a Bezier curve of degree $N-1$, and I know how to calculate the control points of it: [Derivatives of a Bezier Curve](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-der.html)

However, how would i get the partial derivatives of X and Y to calculate a gradient, when I have a multivariate quadratic curve such as this:

$X = f(t) = 3.0*(1-t)^2+2.0*(1-t)t+4.0*t^2$
$Y = g(t) = 9.0*(1-t)^2+1.0*(1-t)t+3.0*t^2$

Where the above describe $(X,Y)$ points in a two dimensional space.

Comment: A Bezier curve is not multivariate. So, there is no partial derivatvies. Its derivative is computed as (dX/dt, dY/dt).

Comment: Bummer.  Is there no (reasonably easy) way to calculate the gradient then?

Comment: The "gradient" I know of is the partial derivatives of a multivariate scalar function. But Bezier curve is actually a univariate vector function. So, I really don't know how to compute its gradient. The closest thing would be the derivative vector, which is computed as (dX/dt, dY/dt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "gradient", I assume you mean the slope $dy/dx$.

First you get the derivative vector:
$$
\left(  \frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt} \right)
$$
and then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{\frac{dy}{dt} }{\frac{dx}{dt} }
$$
As you might expect, this formula has problems when $dx/dt=0$, because this means you have a vertical tangent vector, so infinite slope.

From the general theory of Bezier curves, we know that the curve
$$
f(t) = (1-t)^2 A + 2t(1-t) B + t^2 C
$$
has derivative
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = 2(1-t)(B-A) + 2t(C-B)
$$
So, in your example
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = 2(1-t)(-1) + 2t(2) = 6t-2
$$
$$
\frac{dY}{dt} = 2(1-t)(-8) + 2t(2) = 20t - 16
$$
and so
$$
\frac{dY}{dX} =  \frac{\frac{dY}{dt} }{\frac{dX}{dt} } = \frac{20t-16}{6t-2}
$$

Your reference to partial derivatives is confusing; partial derivatives make sense only when you have a function of **several** independent variables. In the case we're considering here, there is only a single variable, namely the parameter $t$.